# How to save Captured Image in Local Directory and send it to server

Tags: android

Hello Friends i need to capture image and after that need to send good quality image to server i am writing below code for that

```
                  image = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data");
                 Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
                 width = display.getWidth();
                 height = display.getHeight();

                Matrix mat = new Matrix();//removing rotations

                String version= Build.VERSION.SDK;
                Log.e("Version Number ",version);
                if(Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) > 8)
                {
                    mat.preRotate(0);//removing rotations of image
                    //image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image,image.getWidth(),image.getHeight(), true);
                    image = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), mat, true); //removing rotations
                }
                else{
                    mat.preRotate(-90);//removing rotations of image
                    //image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image,image.getWidth(),image.getHeight(), true);
                    image = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), mat, true); //removing rotations
                }
```

my problem is the image which i am getting is like thumbnail image than i was doing so much googling and found this link 
http://dharmendra4android.blogspot.in/2012/04/save-captured-image-to-applications.html
but i am unable to implement it .that would be great help if any body will provide any example project or any easy solution for this .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely in whatever the data you're pulling out of the Intent is.  Where are you fetching this from... what is this Intent?

Comment: onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)

Comment: But the problem is the image which i am getting is of very low quality

Comment: What Activity? Where is this data coming from? What is the image? Why are you expecting a "higher" quality image... in essence... what are you doing?